# Declare all namespaces on root element

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I would like a transform such that  all the namespaces in a document are declared on the documents root element. So that

`<a>
   <ns1:b xmlns:ns1="urn:ns1"/>
   <ns2:c xmlns:ns2="urn:ns2"/>
 </a>`

becomes

`<a xmlns:ns1="urn:ns1" xmlns:ns2="urn:ns2">
    <ns1:b/>
    <ns2:c/>
 </a>`

It doesn't matter if the namespaces appear on the local declarations the point is that they should all have global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why the placement of the namespace declarations should make a difference. Still, if you want, you could try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/a">
    <a xmlns:ns1="urn:ns1" xmlns:ns2="urn:ns2">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or in a more generic way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//namespace::*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

These may work or not, depending on the whim of your XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0):

There are documents for which this is impossible, for example:

```
 <a>
   <ns1:b xmlns:ns1="urn:ns1"/>
   <ns1:b xmlns:ns1="urn:ns2"/>
 </a>
```

and you need to decide what you want done about these.

The "generic" solution from @michael.hor257k should generally work under XSLT 2.0+, with caveats:

(a) it will give you an error if there are conflicting namespace declarations, as described

(b) although this syntax is also accepted under XSLT 1.0, the output isn't well-defined under XSLT 1.0, because serializers have considerable freedom over where to put the serialized namespace declarations.